# How to get the distance between two points (lat, long) in walk

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps, distance

I have two points with Latitude and Longitude like

```
point_one = '4.61378007564, -74.1753083325'
point_two = '4.61339828822, -74.1706325833'
```

I would like to have something like this

```
let distance = getDistance(point_one, point_two)
```

But this distance must be calculated like walking or driving (similar to Google Maps) for example, using Haversine formula I get the linear distance in a sphere but this distance is a line which can be pass above houses, I need the distance walkable by the people.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a routing service like Open Route Service or OSRM.
OSRM will give you the walking or driving travel time and distance.

```js
const point1 = [11.116667, 46.066666]
const point2 = [11.350000, 46.500000]

const url = `https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/walking/${point1[0]},${point1[1]};${point2[0]},${point2[1]}?overview=full`


fetch(url)
.then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```